# How to share a linked list to all process with MPI

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, mpi

Im kinda new with MPI and Im having troubles with this.

Lets say I have this list

```
struct list{
    int number;
    int process;
    list *next;
}
```

I already created the linked list in the main process, but I dont know how to send the linked list to all process so every process can do some operation in a portion of the list.

Comment: what OS? do you insist on multiple processes or multiple threads?

Comment: @IvanAngelov Is Linux and multiples processes

Comment: How about serializing the linked list by turning it into an array, scatter portions of the array and rebuild parts of the linked list on each process ? For instance, `boost.mpi` makes use of `boost.serialization` to serialize and send objects. The basic mistake would be to send the pointer to the next node, which is meaningless on other processes.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to manually send the list around, you would have to traverse and send each and every element of the queue, creating a massive communication overhead.

The best way is to convert the list to a contiguous array of structs and distribute it to the processes via `MPI_Scatter` (or `MPI_Scatterv` if the size of the list is not divisible by the number of ranks). If you must, you can then locally convert it to a linked list on each rank.

Without knowing anything about the rest of the program I'd say there is a strong chance that using a linked list is a bad choice anyway and you should use an array for the data in the first place.

Comment: Can Datatypes be used to send the list without making a copy? Is that an inefficient overkill for small types? What about for large types?